# Deploy redis cluster in single node K8S cluster

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to deploy redis cluster mode in single node k8s cluster. It is creating total 6 replicas. Can we modify this replica count? If yes is there any impact?